# OpenStack Ussuri Immutable Domain/Project/User

Tags: immutability, openstack

I am running OpenStack Ussuri and am trying to find information on making domains, projects, & users immutable.
There does not appear to be a CLI or UI option.  All I can find is:
https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest/admin/resource-options.html
Where, it describes API calls/resource options.

I verified that I cannot delete the default roles.  Now, I would like to understand how to make a domain, project, or user immutable.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know anything about OpenStack, but I think you should add an example of what you are trying to prevent. Why do you want to make things immutable? For whom?

Answer (score 0):

There is no command or API to make a domain, project or user immutable. Given the right privilege, a user can change several details of these identity objects, and there is no way to block this.

Comment: Bernd - immutable resources went in to Train:
Keystone roles, projects, and domains may now be made immutable, so that certain important resources like the default roles or service projects cannot be accidentally modified or deleted.
It appears to be managed through resource options. The doc doesn't explain it too well, unfortunately.  Hence, my question.
It appears that the keystone-manage bootstrap command was updated, but that is run at setup time.
I'm using Devstack ;-)

Comment: Another way of looking at this - do you know how to change the resource options?  
https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/latest//admin/resource-options.html